# Angular - BehaviorSubject in multiple child components

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I have a `BehaviorSubject` declared like this in a service:

`public activeSelectedOrganization = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);`

I have a main component called `user-component` who includes several child components. Let's name them `app-organization-item`

Inside every child component, I set a value to the `BehaviorSubject` - the default value. I also have an `onChange` method so when I will change the value of the `organization` it will change the `BehaviorSubject` value. So far so good.

But having multiple child components inside the parent the `BehaviorSubject` will emit multiple values (as many as child components will be) when you subscribe to it. It's normal.

How can I have `BehaviorSubject` different for every child component? Something is very wrong with my approach.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the `BehaviorSubject` in your child components? It's bad practice to share a central `BehaviorSubject` with multiple components. Why do the components need to modify the `BehaviorSubject`?

Comment: The value of `organization` is based on a select box. So, on `ngOnInit()` I set the default value and on `onChange` I update the `BehaviorSubject` value. Then I subscribe to this Subject and make a `flatMap` based on his value. I finally managed to understand that there is no need for it though and I just created a shared method that sets data. Thank you!